# Getting ".ebextensions" to copy from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, config, csproj, ebextensions, aws-toolkit

The root of my problem is that I want to get HTTPS working for a Blazor app deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  According to all the documentation I'm able to find, I need to add some config files to an ".ebextensions" folder.  I've done that.  I've marked them with a "Build Action" of "Content" and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".  I've even edited the "csproj" file and set the "CopyToPublishDirectory", trying both "true" and "PreserveNewest".  None of these things have helped.  The files get copied to the local "bin" folder properly as I'd expect.  However, after running the "AWS Toolkit" to publish, the files never seem to make it to the server.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the files *were* being copied all along and are getting applied.  I just didn't have enough visibility into the process, and the folder is either hidden or removed after use.

On to the next problem...

Now to get HTTPS actually *working*!